# how to get the exact search result in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, search

i have implemented the search module in my app. The search does not search for the exact phrase, but rather individually for each word in the phrase. For example, if you search for "Comprehensive Metabolic", you would only expect to see the CMP Panels, but the search actually returns every single panel that has either the word "Comprehensive" or "Metabolic", which is a much longer list.
any help can i get?

is there any pipe i can use to filter exact search?

**here is my search component html**

```
  <input #searchInput type="text" (focus)="onFocus($event)" (blur)="onBlur($event)" (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)" placeholder="Search">
```

**its Ts file**

```
  @Input() searchTerm: string = "";
  @Output() onSearchInputUpdate = new EventEmitter();
  @ViewChild("searchInput") searchInputField: ElementRef;

  public searchFocus: boolean;

  private searchTermTimeoutId;
  private waitTime: number = 500; // half a second


    onBlur(event) {
// setTimeout so clearSearch click event has time to be called first
setTimeout(() => {
  if (event.srcElement.value.length === 0) {
    this.searchFocus = false;
  }
}, 100);
 }

  onKeyUp(event) {
 if (this.searchTermTimeoutId) {
  clearTimeout(this.searchTermTimeoutId);
 }
this.searchTermTimeoutId = setTimeout(() => {

this.onSearchInputUpdate.emit(this.searchInputField.nativeElement.value);
  }, this.waitTime);
 }
```

i added this in my component where i am using it

**here parent component's html**

```
   <app-search-list (onSearchInputUpdate)="onSearchFieldUpdate($event)"> 
   </app-search-list>
  <app-test-selection-category-list 
   (onCategorySelect)="updateTestPanelView($event)"></app-test-selection- 
   category-list>
```

**its Ts File**

```
  onSearchFieldUpdate($event) {
  this.searchField = $event;
  this.updateTestPanelView(this.selectedCategoryId);
  }

   updateTestPanelView(categoryId: string) {
this.selectedCategoryId = categoryId;
switch (this.selectedCategoryId) {
  case '-1':
    this.fetchAllTests();
    break;
  case "0":
    this.fetchFavoritesForCategories();
    break;
  default:
    this.fetchTestsForCategory();
   }
 }

fetchAllTests() {

this.testOrderService.getAllTests(this.searchField).subscribe(response => 
  {
  const {panels, tests} = this.extractPanelsAndTests(response);
  this.testSelectionSession = {
    ...this.testSelectionSession,
    PanelsForAll: panels,
    IndividualTestPanelsForAll: tests
  };
  this.store.dispatch(
    new SetTestOrderTestSelectionSession(this.testSelectionSession)
      );
    })
  }

  fetchFavoritesForCategories() {
 this.testOrderService
  .getAllFavorites(this.searchField)
  .subscribe(favorites => {
    this.testSelectionSession = Object.assign(
      {},
      this.testSelectionSession,
      {
        FavoritesByCategory: _.groupBy(favorites, 'CategoryName')
      }
    );
    this.store.dispatch(
      new SetTestOrderTestSelectionSession(this.testSelectionSession)
    );
   });
  }


   fetchTestsForCategory() {
   this.testOrderService
    .getTestsByCategoryId(this.selectedCategoryId, this.searchField)
     .subscribe(categoryResponse => {
      const {panels, tests} = this.extractPanelsAndTests(categoryResponse);

    this.testSelectionSession = Object.assign(
      {},
      this.testSelectionSession,
      {
        PanelsForCategory: panels.map(panel => {
          panel.CategoryId = this.selectedCategoryId;
          return panel;
        }),
        IndividualTestPanelsForCategory: tests.map(
          test => {
            test.CategoryId = this.selectedCategoryId;
            return test;
          }
        )
      }
    );
    this.store.dispatch(
      new SetTestOrderTestSelectionSession(this.testSelectionSession)
     );
    });
   }
```

i am getting every result which has either Comprehensive  or metabolic.
like this
[image]
what can i do to get exact result
any help?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue. As is, your code is very difficult to read for someone not in your team.

Comment: A lot of code is irrelevant to your question. Please try to narrow down the problem, that's too much code to go through. But basically, you are performing a OR search and you want a AND search. This has more to do with your search engine, server-side, than Angular.